# Creating a class with a generic csv reader via a method

Tags: c#, csv, generics, c#-6.0

As a headsup, I'm new to stackoverflow so please do tell me if I'm just bad at searching for a solution.

I have a class library that's able to read csv files depending on the public members of a class and then assign them. However, I don't know a way to avoid a long switch or if else when I want to call/invoke the method.

Here's how I currently use it:

```
public class DataSetup
{
    List<object> ObjList = new List<object>();

    public DataSetup(string file)
    {
        switch (file)
        {
            case "Persons.csv":
                AssignCsvData<Person>(file);
                break;
            case "Address.csv":
                AssignCsvData<Address>(file);
                break;
        }
    }

    public void AssignCsvData<T>(string file) where T : CsvableBase, new()
    {
        var cr = new CsvReader<T>();
        var csvObjs = cr.Read(file);
        foreach (var obj in csvObjs)
        {
            ObjList.Add(obj);
        }
    }

}
```

The switch is not "done", since I'm hoping for a better way.
So is there a way to call the AssignCsvData without the switch?

So far I've tried taking a type as a parameter for the constructor, but I can't use it as a type when it's a variable.

Comment: I think another way to do this is to have dictionary with csvName,Type and using Activator create Generic Type but this will cause a lot of problems and I think that you had better use switch.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid the switch statement? You can use enum to declare the different types so that a string is avoided to switch on, which is a bit safer.

Comment: I mostly want to avoid it due to the fact that I'm lazy. Also I'd like it to be fully generic. I am in a learning stage though, so is it actually better to use a switch, at least in this case?

Answer (score 0):

If the name of the file always represents a class. In your case there is a mismatch between Persons.csv and Person, but say they do match then the following could work using reflection, rather than a switch statement:

```cs
var type = Type.GetType(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file));

var method = typeof(Processor)
        .GetMethod("AssignCsvData")
        .MakeGenericMethod(type);

method.Invoke(new Processor(), file);
```

NOTE: If you'd like to test this in LinqPad, don't forget to use the "UserQuery+" namespace to get the type. i.e.:

```cs
var type = Type.GetType($"UserQuery+{Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file)}");
```